# iPhone - preventing slowdown due to setting a image to an UIImageView

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, drawing, slowdown

I have a method that gets the image taken from the iPhone camera, put it into an UIImageView, then call another method for custom drawing into a custom UIView.

I've noticed that when I take the photo from the front camera of the iPhone 4, the custom UIView drawing is ok and smooth. When taking the photo from the back camera, then the custom drawing is jerky, sometime it even do not display all the "frames" it has to display.

**How may I prevent those jerks in a conrete way, knowing that my custom animation MUST begin when the image is displayed into the UIImageView ?**

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    UIImage* pickedImage = [[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] retain];
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum (pickedImage, self, @selector(photoSaved:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
   self.photoShoot.image = pickedImage;
    [pickedImage release];

    [self.customviewfordrawings makeyourdrawstuff];
}
```

When commenting the `self.photoShoot.image = pickedImage;`, no more jerk whatever camera is used.

Note : The `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum`call may not be in cause because putting it or not in the code does not affect the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps the image is a little too big to display smoothly. Try creating a resized version and display that in the imageView.

Comment: I did. It takes almost 1 second, it's very long. Do you know a way to reduce the image quickly and with a downsampling that can adjust the retina display ? Because xxxx.bounds.size.width return 320, and downsampling to 320 make the onscreen image blur.

Comment: To avoid the slowdown, you could downsize the image in a separate thread.

Comment: The problem is not anymore a slowdown problem but a just "too slow" problem  :-)